# Get an event object from win32evtlog.EvtQuery results

Tags: python, event-log, pywin32

I'd like to search the Windows Event Log for events by their attributes.
[`win32evtlog.EvtQuery`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.3/pywin32/win32evtlog__EvtQuery_meth.html) looks like just the thing.

So, I can e.g. query for system starting events and retrieve the last one like this:

```
import win32evtlog
hevq=win32evtlog.EvtQuery("System",win32evtlog.EvtQueryReverseDirection,\
        "*[System[Provider[@Name='eventlog'] and (EventID=6009)]]",None)
hev=win32evtlog.EvtNext(hevq,1)[0]
```

But what I get is some random handle which all I can do with, according to the [`EvtNext` docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa385405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), is pass it to [`EvtRender`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa385471%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get an XML representation.

But, I don't want to parse it and would like to get a good ol' `PyEventLogRecord` instead like I do with [`win32evtlog.ReadEventLog`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.3/pywin32/win32evtlog__ReadEventLog_meth.html).

Is there a way to do this while still using `EvtQuery`? I don't wanna read all the events sequentially, there are tens of thousands of them.

Comment: @LoïcFaureLacroix please stop searching for posts to change `sh1t` to `shit`. Better would be just to edit out `shit` entirely and put something useful there.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker he's the only one from ~140 viewers who saw anything inappropriate. Not a big deal, but I assert the post has lost some flavor as a result of the edit war.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Vista Event Log API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385780%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (functions with names starting with `Evt`) does not use the [`EVENTLOGRECORD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa363646%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure (which is what `PyEventLogRecord` wraps), nor are the "new" events designed to be representable with it. A string in XML format actually *is* the "native" export representation now rather than some C structure (this explains why Vista's Event Viewer is so extremely sluggish, unlike its XP's counterpart). And only with this API one can access the Vista-introduced "Application and Service logs".

- The only alternative to the XML is to only output some fields by calling [`EvtCreateRenderContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) first (which is not supported by `pywin32`. It only supports outputting the full XML out of the box).

`pywin32` doesn't include any facilities to parse the XML - probably because the original API doesn't either and the authors didn't want to encumber the library with irrelevant stuff. `Wevtapi.dll` doesn't use a full-fledged XML library so it likely only outputs some small subset of XML which can be parsed in a similarly ad-hoc manner - but this would be a time bomb as M$ gives no guarantees about what subset it is.

---

I ended up parsing "this sh1t" with `lxml`. Knowing that, loony as it is, it's the native representation now, made me feel better about installing and encumbering my program with such a major library for such a simple and unrelated task.